# Get and suspend threads of process in CMD

Tags: multithreading, cmd, process

I want to suspend a thread in a process and also I want to get all of the threads.
But I googled and didn't find a method to list or change it.
Example, what I mean:
dwm.exe has these threads inside: http://prntscr.com/hru52n (Opened with process explorer).

But I want to make it on cmd (.bat). I really do not know what I should do.
I would be happy if someone helps me.

Thank you!

Comment: What is the point of this?

Answer (score -1):

#### I want to suspend a thread in a process

Why? It is not advised to do this as there is a good chance you will deadlock the process:

> Q: What is the result of suspending a thread in the middle of a
>   threadsafe operation?
>
> [The] Critical section never gets unlocked if you’re inside it.
>
> Q: What happens if – subsequently – you try to access that same object
>   (in this case, the console) from another thread?
>
> Deadlock…

Source [Why you should never suspend a thread](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20031209-00/?p=41573)